# Parse Long from String exception

Tags: java, android, parsing, long-integer

I got a very bizzared exception when trying to parse the simple String into a long value.

```
public class Utils {
public static double tryParseLong(String s) {
    try {
        return Long.parseLong("45.6", 10);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

}

`java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "45.6"`

Comment: long l1 = (long)Double.parseDouble("12.2") ;

Comment: Isn't it completely obvious that 45.6 is not long? Long values don't have floating point.

Comment: do you at least know what is a long? 45.6 is not long in any programming language

Answer (score 2):

45.6 is not a long, it is a float or double, hence the error. Use Double.parseDouble.

Answer (score 1):

"45.6" is not a valid value for Long becuase **Long can't contain numbers with floating point** and that's why you are getting exception.

If you want to parse only Integral part (i.e. 45) then you can first parse Double from String and then cast it to Long like this,

```
(long) Double.parseDouble("45.6");
```

It will return 45.